# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to open an .exe file

Tags: python, optimization, google-colaboratory, pyomo, scip

I am trying to open an .exe file from my drive to access the executable path to solve my optimization problem but I get the [Errno 13] PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/scip.exe'. What I am trying to do in the following code is simple but I don't understand why it is giving this error.

```
#SCIP "Solving Constraint Integer Programs" solver (LP, NLP, MIP and MINLP):
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive", force_remount=True)
os.environ['MyDrive'] = '/content/drive/MyDrive'

solver = SolverFactory('scip', executable='/content/drive/MyDrive/scip.exe')
solver.solve(model).write()
```

The error is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-fa76e8283229> in <cell line: 24>()
     22 
     23 solver = SolverFactory('scip', executable='/content/drive/MyDrive/scip.exe')#.solve(model).write()
---> 24 solver.solve(model).write()
     25 
     26 

6 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, restore_signals, gid, gids, uid, umask, start_new_session)
   1861                     if errno_num != 0:
   1862                         err_msg = os.strerror(errno_num)
-> 1863                     raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
   1864                 raise child_exception_type(err_msg)
   1865 

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/content/drive/MyDrive/scip.exe'
```

What should be the code to solve this problem? What should I try?

Comment: The executable file and/or one of its containing folders must be owned by a different user account, and your current user does not have permission to access it.  What are the exact permissions on `/content/drive/MyDrive/scip.exe`, and on all of the containing folders?

Comment: @JohnGordon this is my google drive, so theoretically it should be fine regarding being owned by me. My google drive has a folder containing my colab notebooks, as well as I am trying to access the solver .exe file in the drive in a different folder other than the folder having the colab notebooks .ipynb. What I do not understand is why the permission is being denied. Regarding permissions in my google drive I do not know how to exactly check that in the sense of having a link with google colab code

Comment: Are you trying to run an *Win* executable on *Nix*?

Comment: @CristiFati Hello, I want to execute it in google colab environment. Yes, the executable is a windows file. Unfortunatelly it is giving this error. Could you know how to help from this perspective?